# How to I mount a folder from my computer into a specific spot on my VM AND have it owned by me, not root?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, mount, virtualbox, shared-folders

I am running a VirtualBox with Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop, and I need access on this guest to a folder on the host; however, the access needs to be full so I can run Wordpress. I have added myself to the vboxsf group after using the built in mounting for Ubuntu desktop, no result. I've tried chown, no result. How can I mount the shared folder on my VM and have it not owned by root and have all permissions?

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question as your other question?

Comment: OP already asked this question in another place.  Check the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98740/discussion-between-avig-and-thomas-ward) from the other question i gave you a potential solution.